# Interchange limits (sequence of integrals)

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d \geq 1$) such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |p_n - q_n| = 0 \, .$$
Let $f, g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R})$, let $f_n(x) = f(x - p_n), g_n(x) = f(x - q_n) \ \forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f_n, g_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R})$ and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert f_n g_n \rVert_{L^1} = 0 \, .$$

Hint: prove it supposing $f, g$ have got compact support, then the general case.

I've been able to prove it in the "compact case", now I'm trying to solve the general case. My reasoning is the following:

Let $E_N = [- N, N]^d$, then $\mathbb{R}^d = \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} E_N$, since both $|f_n|$ and $|g_n|$ are non-negative measurable functions and $E_N \subseteq E_{N + 1}$, we can deduce
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f_n(x) g_n(x)| d x = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{E_N} |f_n(x) g_n(x)| d x \quad \forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Now I would like to prove that this limit is $0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f_n(x) g_n(x)| d x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{E_N} |f_n(x) g_n(x)| d x$$
Can I interchange the limits $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty}$? (And why?)

Comment: This doesn't work. You have to approximate $f$ by a continuous function with compact support w.r.t. $L^{1}$ norm.

Comment: @geetha290krm Should I approximate just $f$ or both $f$ and $g$? I'm trying right now (using this approximation and triangular inequality in the integrals) but I always end up with integrals that are product of two $L^1$ functions (and at most one of the them has got compact support), I don't know how to "overstimate" (with something "small") those integrals (I know about the density of $C^\infty_c$ functions in $L^1$)